# How can I ignore a whole git repository in Visual Studio Code?

Tags: git, visual-studio-code

It’s not about using .gitignore to ignore certain files, it’s about completely excluding that particular repository from file watcher of VS Code.

It complains that there’s more than 5000 files are opened and then just hanged my laptop. This repository has insane amount of files, and it’s located in my home folder as my configs are stored in git, in .gitignore I’ve added all files to ignore, and when I need to stash the files I’m using `git add -f <file>`.

As you can see on the picture, the repository "holms" is always opened, and it's causing me issues. This is parent repo, which is in my home folder. How can I ignore it completely? If I close that repo, it appears again after like 3 minutes of working in a editor

[image]

Comment: Tools -> Options -> Source Control -> Plug in selection -> Set to none.

Comment: https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode/issues/35480, when done, should help you

Comment: @miqdadamirali vscode doesn't have such menu options. You probably talking about full visual studio

Comment: @max630 it's not exactly that, in repo panel there's previous repo opened, i'm closing it every time, would be nice just to ignore it already

Comment: @holms My mistake on that. For VS Code, try the following. File -> Preference -> Settings and in the custom `User Settings` (Right panel), add the following: `"git.enabled"`: false,`

Comment: Well i do need git for other repositories, what does this solve?

Answer (score 60, accepted):

Had the same problem, try adding option:

`"git.autoRepositoryDetection": false`

and close repo from your parent (home) folder. It shouldn't appear again.

Update:

There's now an option to watch only repositories for opened files:
`"git.autoRepositoryDetection": "openEditors"`

This way, if you open any file in a specific repository, vscode will only watch it.

Comment: The second setting saved me from ignoring the whole repo directory from the workspace; thanks for that! Now my submodules show up in the explorer without cluttering the Version Control sidebar!

Answer (score 48):

Another solution is to use the `Ignored Repositories` in settings, for example to ignore the repository in home directory you can add:

```
"git.ignoredRepositories": [
    "/home/holms"
],
```

Or from the settings editor (my username is obi)

[image]

Comment: This solution was the only one that really worked for me. I have sub repos that just cluttered up the Source Control pane and this did the trick.

Comment: worked for me too, but only if I add the paths with double-backslashes (I'm on windows) e.g. someting like `D:\\folder1\\folder2`

Comment: This is working solution especially if you have a repositories within a repository.

Comment: This should be the accepted solution, because it is the only one that is explicit enough for every use case.

Answer (score 5):

In VS Code 1.80, all you should need to do is close the repository. From [the release notes](https://code.visualstudio.com/updates/v1_80#_close-repository-improvements):

> In the past, users could close a repository either using the **Git: Close Repository** command or the **Close Repository** action in the Source Control view but there were certain actions (for example, opening a file from the closed repository) that would reopen the closed repository. This milestone we have made some improvements so the fact that a repository is closed is now persisted per workspace. Users can reopen closed repositories using the **Git: Reopen Closed Repositories...** command.

You can close a repository using the "Close Repository" item in the context menu of the repository in the SCM View, or the `Git: Close Repository` command in the command palette.

Answer (score 4):

You could also select which repositories to hide manually:

[image]

Comment: Seems to reset every time I restart VSCode.

Comment: Yeah this does indeed reset when you reload the window

Comment: This [answer by starball](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76657319/6908282) is more latest - which talks about how to persistently close a repository.

Answer (score 3):

Open `source control repositories view [image]
And select the main repository you want. It won't be reset after restarting.

Comment: Only solution that worked for me, all the other flags had no effect when set in the project's vscode settings

Answer (score 0):

Another option is to look inside `.vscode/settings.json` and adjust the settings there.
In my case, I wanted to see the contents of the `Library` folder, so I set

```
    "Library/":false,
```

Previously it was set to  `true`.