# Prevent Git from tracking all of my packages/libraries/modules when I open a new VSCode window

Tags: git, visual-studio-code

Git slows down my programs & causes my terminal to crash and display this message:

`Restarting the terminal because the connection to the shell process was lost...`

every time I open a new window in VSCode (i.e. not a file from an existing repo).

Its almost like its trying to track every file in my computer. Everything runs fine once it caps at 10k pending changes but I want to put a stop to the problem from the source; whatever that may be.

[This is the closest issue I could find](https://www.reddit.com/r/learnprogramming/comments/qospga/how_to_discard_all_changes_in_source_control_git/), it seems like they have the same problem but I'd rather not wait and discard changes every time I open a new window.

This is an example of the kind of files that are being tracked

[image: Screenshot from source control sidebar]

It seems that the only solution is to sign out every time but this option is worst-case-scenario at the moment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[From here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/49325617/6309), you can:

- set `"git.autoRepositoryDetection": "openEditors"`: a repository will be tracked only if you open a file from it (from [issue 53668](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/53668#issuecomment-403398048)).
- and/or add a path of a specific repository to `git.ignoredRepositories`

In your case, only the first option seems practical, as you have too many repositories to "ignore".