# How to prevent VSCode from opening all git repositories at startup?

Tags: git, visual-studio-code

Some of the folders in my VSCode workspace contain a large number of git repositories. Whenever I open VSCode, it spends a lot of time opening all these repositories. Usually I only need one or two of these repositories. I can close the unneeded repositories, but it takes a lot of time to open and then close them. Can I change the default behavior, such that no git repository is opened at startup?

Answer (score 6):

I found a good answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52344801/8525450) that discusses these entries for settings.json

`"git.autoRepositoryDetection": false`
or
`git.autoRepositoryDetection": "openEditors"`

And after trying that out, I realized in my case I had a repo with submodules, so VSCode was following the information in the git repo.  If someone tries the above setting with no luck, in your project root run

```
git submodule status
```

if you get back a list, you can tell VSCode to not open those with

```
"git.detectSubmodules": false,
```

For completeness:
Presumably you only want the behavior in a specific workspace.  To change workspace settings use command

```
Preferences: Open Workspace Settings (JSON)
```

as described [here](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/getstarted/settings#_workspace-settingsjson-location)

Answer (score 1):

Setting `"git.ignoredRepositories": ["<repo_name>"]` in the workspace settings JSON seems to help (the change is applied after restarting VSCode)

Comment: Is there a way to ignore all repositories, so that I do not have to specify each of them by name?

Comment: @ErelSegal-Halevi you may try typing `"git.` into the settings, and autocompletion will give you possible settings. However I didn't specifically find anything for your request