# Some of my workspace Git repositories no longer show up in my VS Code Source Control View. Why? How can I restore them to that view?

Tags: git, visual-studio-code, source-control-explorer

I have a bunch of repositories that I'm working in by using a workspace. I discovered last week that (as far as i know) 2 aren't automatically opening anymore in source control.
[image]

I do see them in my explorer tree and can open them in a separate window from which I can use source control. But needing to open a new window every time for these repo's defies the purpose of my workspace...

Went through all places were settings are set and did a global search to check if these were added to the ignored repo list (`git.ignoredRepositories`) but they aren't in there.

I also deleted the repo's and cloned them again, but the same issue still persists.

The outcome I expected was to find the 'problematic' repo's somewhere in my config to be ignored, delete that and have every repo in my source control again.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I'd suggest that you check if you closed the repositories (see also my answer post in [How can I ignore a whole git repository in Visual Studio Code?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/49325617/11107541) for info about that feature). You can reopen closed repositories by using the `Git: Reopen Closed Repositories...` command in the [command palette](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/getstarted/userinterface#_command-palette).

You already mentioned that you checked your `git.ignoredRepositories`. I'd also suggest to see if you've done anything with your `git.autoRepositoryDetection`, `git.scanRepositories`, `git.repositoryScanIgnoredFolders`, and `git.repositoryScanMaxDepth` settings that could be causing this.

Note that [a change was made to this feature in VS Code 1.80](https://code.visualstudio.com/updates/v1_80#_close-repository-improvements) to improve persistence of whether a repository is closed.