# Git nested repo in Visual Studio Code

Tags: git, visual-studio-code, git-submodules

On a modding project, I have a top-level repository with all my stuff. Then there's a nested repo for a script package I've forked. Since it's standalone, I want to keep it separate from my mod project, but be open to do pull requests on the sub-repo. So the structure is as follows:

```
MyProject.git
- top-level stuff
  - scripts
    - myScripts
    - scriptPack.git (nested repo)
```

Since I don't want submodules, I've added the scriptPack folder to the .gitignore of the top-level repo.

I'm using Visual Studio Code to work on the project and to commit and push changes. I don't know what changed, but before, I had both repositories listed separately under the source control tab in VS Code, so I could push changes individually. Now I no longer see the nested repo, but instead the "scriptPack"-folder was listed as a change in my top-level folder, one that I cannot discard or otherwise interact with. From what I know, this is the behaviour when submodules come into play, but I'm very inexperienced with submodules.

I simply deleted the scriptPack folder, and cloned it again, now it's no longer showing up on my top-level repo, just like I expected it to. But now VS Code won't show me the nested repo anymore, so my question is rather simple:

How do I get the nested repo to show in VS Code again?

Comment: Don't "nest" repos / working trees. That is an incoherent architecture.

Comment: please check if https://stackoverflow.com/a/76951439/11107541 answers your question and let me know. if it does, let's close this as a duplicate.

Comment: @starball, not quite, but along the way I've found a git setting in VS Code that did the trick for me: "Repository Scan Max Depth" was set to only 1 and since the scripts folder is quite far down the line it just didn't scan for that. So thanks for pointing me in the right direction.

Answer (score 0):

For deeply nested repositories, VS Code's default for repo-scans is not sufficient, as it will scan for only one level below.
Setting it to unlimited in my case made the repository show up again.

[image: Repository Scan Max Depth]