# Git in VSCode - extra repository

Tags: git, github, visual-studio-code

I am trying to get just the Angular files of my project to commit to a local repository and push to github.

In my experimenting I have managed to end up with this `bird-app` and `bird-project` - I presume they are both repositories, but I can't see why one project would have duplicate repositories?

[image]

Are they repositories or branches? And how do I get rid of the second one as its not needed.

Bird-App is \users\bird-app;
Bird-Project is \users\bird-app\bird-project

I tried rmdir - failed to remove as not empty (but no files in there) and git branch --delete didn't work either as bot found (presume not a branch).

It would be good to know how to do it in both UI and CLI.

Comment: I don't know the UI but check these commands in the console to answer those questions easily: `git remote show` to list all remotes to this tepo and `git branch -a` to list all branches (local and remote).

Comment: Its not a branch.

Comment: "In my experimenting" -- that may be the cause. What exactly did you do? Further, check for `.git` directories with Git repository data. What does `git remote -v` give you in the parent of those directories?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to keep both of them but just hide one from VS Code, use [VS Code's "Close Repository" feature](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76657319/11107541). If you want to actually get rid of / delete one of them, then just... get rid of it (delete its [.git directory](https://git-scm.com/docs/git#_discussion)).