# vscode source controle error in an environment where wsl2 and vscode exist together

Tags: git, visual-studio-code, wsl-2

I am currently installing and using wsl2 and vscode in a cloud environment(like EC2).
(I do not want to link the two)

I can't see my source changes in the vscode source control tab.
Even though I only have one repository, all folders under the project are shown as repositories in source control...
And the branch doesn't appear in the status bar at the bottom of vscode...

Is there any additional git settings needed in vscode?
Or does installing wsl2 have any effect?

git,vscode Delete and reinstall

Comment: "_all folders under the project are shown as repositories in source control_" maybe you want to see https://stackoverflow.com/q/49325617/11107541