# How can I prevent VS Code from auto-detecting git repositories in parent directories of the current workspace?

Tags: git, visual-studio-code, vscode-git

I just joined a project with a lot of sub-projects and terrible .gitignore definition, ending up with VS Code scanning 5000+ changes across the solution and ignoring the changes that I just made.

I tried to open the sub-project I'm working on in VS Code but it still attaches to the parent .git and scans the whole solution.

Is there any VS Code configuration I'd be missing that would have Git focus on the current directory rather than the whole solution, considering that I'm working on an offline environment without extensions ?

Also, would avoid the obvious 'just update your .gitignore' answer ...

Comment: do you have git repo's inside other git repo's

Comment: It's not clear what action in VSCode is in cause. What's "scanning 5000+ changes"? Is that when you open the Git tab?

Comment: Looks like this : 
```txt
- Project
|-- .git
|-- sub1/
|-- sub2/
`-- sub3/
```

Say I'm making changes on sub3, but VS Code Git tab detects build changes in sub1 and sub2, thus not showing my changes in sub3

Comment: If you don't need all other repository files, have a look at 'partial clone'. Otherwise, maybe 'skip-worktree' feature. But it's not clear if you see 5k files changed (not normal, maybe eol issue) or it's just perf problem because scanning a lot of files?

Comment: Yup, not clear why you see changes in files you didn't modify. Is that what you see? Or did you mean something else? What kind of changes are detected if that's the case?

Comment: Build changes not declared in .gitignore, most likely

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're probably looking for the `git.openRepositoryInParentFolders` setting. Quoting defaultSettings.json:

> ```json
> // Control whether a repository in parent folders of workspaces or open files should be opened.
> //  - always: Always open a repository in parent folders of workspaces or open files.
> //  - never: Never open a repository in parent folders of workspaces or open files.
> //  - prompt: Prompt before opening a repository the parent folders of workspaces or open files.
> "git.openRepositoryInParentFolders": "prompt",
> ```

It defaults to `"prompt"`, so you should have gotten a prompt about it...

---

Okay, the asker clarified that they're on VS Code 1.57. That's... a pretty old version of VS Code now. I'd suggest to update. Anyhow, that explains it. The setting I mention above was [added in VS Code 1.75](https://code.visualstudio.com/updates/v1_75#_git-repositories-in-parent-folders). As mentioned in the release notes, the behaviour prior to 1.75 is essentially the same as `"git.openRepositoryInParentFolders": "always"`.

Note that there is also a feature to close repositories (see [How can I ignore a whole git repository in Visual Studio Code?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/49325617/11107541)).

Comment: That looks like what I'm looking for, but I can't find that property on VS Code v1.57.1